# How to render a part of menu in ZF2

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2

I'm trying to render only a part of the menu configuration in my ZF2 application.
I cant find anything about how to do this.

My configuration is:

```php
array(
    'default' => array(
        'dashbord' => array(
            'label' => 'Dashbord',
            'route' => 'nav',
        ),
        'settings' => array(
            'label' => 'Settings',
            'route' => 'nav',
            'pages' => array(
            'Api Settings' => array(
                'label'=>'NAV_API_SETTINGS',
                'route'=>'nav'
             ),
        ),
    ),
    'NEW' =>array(
        'dashboard' => array(
            'label' => 'dashboard',
            'route' => 'nav',
        )
    )
);
```

So i have the subsets default and NEW.
I need to render only the subset "NEW" of my menu. How do i do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it is good that you are asking questions, but please learn [how to format code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) so that it displays properly. It is good practice to format code for readability when you are presenting it to people to ask them to read it, understand it and help you with it. Also on SO, we like to see what you have done to try and solve your problem for yourself, such as code or references to research you have already carried out. This question currently reads as a 'gimme codez' question and is likely to be closed/down voted or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in some Module.php or where you create your navigation, assuming your given config is stored in `$config` and you have access to the ServiceManager in `$serviceManager`

```
$navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation($config['NEW']);
$serviceManager->setService('new_navigation', $navigation);
```

in a view/layout

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('new_navigation') ?>
```

PS: in any Module.php you can get the serviceManager like this:

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e)
{
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
}
```